# How to decode a Base64 string in Scala or Java?

Tags: java, python, scala, base64, decoding

I have a string encoded in Base64:

```
eJx9xEERACAIBMBKJyKDcTzR_hEsgOxjAcBQFVVNvi3qEsrRnWXwbhHOmzWnctPHPVkPu-4vBQ==
```

How can I decode it in Scala language?

I tried to use:

```
val bytes1 = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(compressed_code_string)
```

But when I compare the byte array with the correct one that I generated in Python language, there is an error. Here is the command I used in python:

```
import base64
base64.urlsafe_b64decode(compressed_code_string)
```

The Byte Array in Scala is:

`(120, -100, 125, -60, 65, 17, 0, 32, 8, 4, -64, 74, 39, 34, -125, 113, 60, -47, -2, 17, 44, -128, -20, 99, 1, -64, 80, 21, 85, 77, -66, 45, -22, 18, -54, -47, -99, 101, -16, 110, 17, -50, -101, 53, -89, 114, -45, -57, 61, 89, 15, -69, -2, 47, 5)`

And the one generated in python is:

`(120, -100, 125, -60, 65, 17, 0, 32, 8, 4, -64, 74, 39, 34, -125, 113, 60, -47, -2, 17, 44, -128, -20, 99, 1, -64, 80, 21, 85, 77, -66, 45, -22, 18, -54, -47, -99, 101, -16, 110, 17, -50, -101, 53, -89, 114, -45, -57, 61, 89, 15, -69, -18, 47, 5)`

Note that there is a single difference in the end of the array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is unfortunately [not just one Base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history).  The `-` character doesn't have the same representation in all encodings.  For example, in the MIME encoding, it's not used at all.  In the encoding for URLs, it is a value of 62--and this is the one that Python is using.  The default sun.misc decoder wants `+` for 62.  If you change the `-` to `+`, you get the correct answer (i.e. the Python answer).

In Scala, you can convert the string `s` to MIME format like so:

```
s.map{ case '-' => '+'; case '_' => '/'; case c => c }
```

and then the Java MIME decoder will work.

Answer (score 16):

In Scala, Encoding a String to Base64 and decoding back to the original String using Java APIs:

```
import java.util.Base64
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

scala> val bytes = "foo".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
bytes: Array[Byte] = Array(102, 111, 111)

scala> val encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes)
encoded: String = Zm9v

scala> val decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded)
decoded: Array[Byte] = Array(102, 111, 111)

scala> val str = new String(decoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
str: String = foo
```

Answer (score 4):

Both Python and Java are correct in terms of the decoding. They are just using a different RFC for this purpose. Python library is using `RFC 3548` and the used java library is using `RFC 4648` and `RFC 2045`.

Changing the hyphen(-) into a plus(+) from your input string will make the both decoded byte data are similar.